# mongo client doesnt read CA file if file is passed as parameter in URL

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am trying to use AWS DocumentDB.

This command works fine:

```
mongo --tls --host my.cluster-random.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --tlsCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username mongo --password 'supersecure'
```

This command doesn't:

```
mongo 'mongodb://mongo@my.cluster-random.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&tls=true'
```

I get the error:

```
SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

My impression is that the second case file doesn't get read. If I put the wrong file name in the first command - I get an OpenSSL error:

```
Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration cannot read certificate authority file:
```

In the second case it's like doesn't matter at all. Any combination of TLS options like "ignore" didn't give any effect either.

I am lost a bit. Any advice?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Since in my case I cannot use command-line option but need the connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... for what ever reason its not supported in mongo shell. From documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

tlsCAFile - This connection string option is not available for the mongo shell. Use the command-line option instead.